# Cannot run exe file with ProcessBuilder in Java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am trying to run an exe file while setting some parameters for it like this:

```
myExePath -ini myIniPath -x myConfigFilePath
```

When I run it from the command line it works perfectly. But when I try running it from my Java code the process starts but after a while is not responding anymore so I have to forcibly close it. I am using this Java code:

```
    List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<String>();
    parameters.add(myexePath);
    parameters.add("-ini ");
    parameters.add(myIniPath);
    parameters.add("-x ");
    parameters.add(myConfigPath
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(parameters);
    Process process = builder.start();

    try {
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println("Process was interrupted");
    }
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you paste the stack trace?

Comment: I don't get any...after running waitFor() the process just stops responding and I have to close it from task manager and only then I can advance in my Java code

Comment: It looks like myExePath child process is blocking. What does it do? Why does it take a long time to complete, causing you to kill the child process? Does it require a separate console input? Does it require a separate console output? If it does any, it must not inherit the std I/O handles of its parent process so that it won't block the parent process's std I/O handles. It can be achieved through anonymous pipes under Windows. I think this is now supported in Java 7. In prior Java version, you have to use JNI or JNA to create a child process with anonymous pipes.

Answer (score 1):

Does the exe use stdout, stderr, stdin? You should always read from them or close them. Depending on the implementation and buffer size not reading from them could lead to blocking.

Comment: See this page for an example: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4

Comment: looked at the example...added the InputStream part and now it works. Not sure why it works, but thanks @martiell

Comment: I guess the rest of the article probably explains it; I didn't look. I just linked directly to the code, hoping it'd help you get things working faster. I think the idea is that the buffer has a limited size, so if you don't read from it, then the process has to wait until there's space. Otherwise, the output would be lost.

Comment: If you are looking at the **GoodWindowsExec.java** example and using it, then you are not actually running from your executable but from Windows command interpreter (**command.exe** or **cmd.exe** spawned by Java `Process`) that eventually spawns your executable. The codes in the page mentioned in the article uses Java `Process` to spawn a Windows command interpreter which the latter will spawn a child process. In your original code in your problem, you are trying to spawn the executable itself using Java `Process`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps, but why you use spaces?
e.g.:   `parameters.add("-x ");`
You don't need them.

What you can also try is to put all your parameters in an array and use another constructor of ProcessBuilder which takes an array as argument.

Comment: i tried both with space and without, with " for the paths and without, in an array String[] and a list...it is not working

Comment: I remember to have similar problem. My process was executed in a loop and after some number of cycles it hung. Do you use loops or threads? Can you post more code?

Comment: threads...i checked again in the task manager and I saw that when I am running the exe from the command line it starts only one thread and when I run it from the Java code there are 2 threads created. I think that is the reason for the blockage but I don't understand why there are 2 threads created.

Comment: I think it's ok that your have 2 threads. One is main thread for java application and another for external process you have started.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should first get a reference to the `Runtime`.

You could do this
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(parameters.toString());`

Your string from the parameters list may need a bit formatting.